# overflow: scroll; CSS adding border to edge of page?

Tags: html, css, scroll, border

I have a div with the following css:

`overflow: scroll;`

However, it appears that there's a border being added by the browser (?) where the scrollbar should appear if it was visible (even if it is not visible). I have inspected the css within dev tools, and cannot find a reference to this styling. How do I hide this scrollbar styling?

Here's an example screenshot - the red arrow points at the right edge of the screen, I did not add that border styling. It disappears if I remove the `overflow: scroll;` style rule.

[image]

Note, I am seeing this behavior in both Chrome and Safari (latest versions of both).

Comment: Try adding `overflow-y:hidden;` along with `overflow:scroll;` like this: `overflow: scroll; overflow-y:hidden;`

Comment: @turing_machine let me know if that works.

Comment: It may be because it overflows the parent horizontally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting the overflow property to 'scroll' clips the content to size. This prevents the content from exceeding it's container borders horizontally and vertically. It also places a scrollbar horizontally and vertically, regardless of whether it is needed or not.

**This will display both scroll bars:**

```
<div id="div1">
  Content
</div>

#div1 {
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

The 'auto' value will display a scroll bar vertically, horizontally or both as required.

**Change the CSS to:**

```
#div1 {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

You can also set the overflow property for horizontal or vertical only. You can use this over auto if you want to guarantee there can't be a vertical scroll bar.

**Change the CSS to:**

```
#div1 {
    overflow-x:scroll; /* Set the overflow horizontal property to clip the content 
and display a horizontal scroll bar. */
} 
    overflow-y:hidden; /* Set the overflow vertical property to clip the content, 
hide the vertical scroll bar and any content outside of the top/bottom borders. */
}
```